# RedirectToAction not doing anything

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have this method which should redirect to the Index method of the same controller. This method is called using ajax.

```
public IActionResult ActualizarJornada(string data)
        {
            DateTime jornadaDiariaEntrada = DateTime.Parse(data.Split(';')[0]);
            DateTime jornadaDiariaSalida = DateTime.Parse(data.Split(';')[1]);
            DateTime jornadaFinDeSemanaEntrada = DateTime.Parse(data.Split(';')[2]);
            DateTime jornadaFinDeSemanaSalida = DateTime.Parse(data.Split(';')[3]);

            int jornadaDiariaId = Convert.ToInt32(data.Split(';')[4]);
            int jornadaFinDeSemanaId = Convert.ToInt32(data.Split(';')[5]);
            int empleadoJornadaId = Convert.ToInt32(data.Split(';')[6]);
            
            JornadaDiarium jd = _context.JornadaDiaria.Where(x=> x.JornadaDiariaId == jornadaDiariaId).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            jd.JornadaDiariaId = jornadaDiariaId;
            jd.HoraEntrada = jornadaDiariaEntrada;
            jd.HoraSalida = jornadaDiariaSalida;
            _context.JornadaDiaria.Update(jd);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            JornadaFinDeSemana jfd = _context.JornadaFinDeSemanas.Where(x=>x.JornadaFinDeSemanaId == jornadaFinDeSemanaId).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            jfd.JornadaFinDeSemanaId = jornadaFinDeSemanaId;
            jfd.HoraEntrada = jornadaFinDeSemanaEntrada;
            jfd.HoraSalida = jornadaFinDeSemanaSalida;
            _context.JornadaFinDeSemanas.Update(jfd);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            EmpleadoJornadum ej = _context.EmpleadoJornada.Where(x => x.EmpleadoJornadaId == empleadoJornadaId).Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
            ej.JornadaDiariaId = jornadaDiariaId;
            ej.JornadaDiaria.HoraEntrada = jornadaDiariaEntrada;
            ej.JornadaDiaria.HoraSalida = jornadaDiariaSalida;
            ej.JornadaFinDeSemana.HoraEntrada = jornadaFinDeSemanaEntrada;
            ej.JornadaFinDeSemana.HoraSalida = jornadaFinDeSemanaSalida;
            ej.JornadaFinDeSemanaId = jornadaFinDeSemanaId;

            _context.EmpleadoJornada.Update(ej);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            
            
            
            Helper helper = new Helper();
            helper.ActualizarHorasExtra(ej.EmpleadoId);
            

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { data },
                url: "/EmpleadoJornada/ActualizarJornada",
                
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    

                    
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                  
                },
                
            });
        });
    });
```

Index Method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var horasExtraDbContext = _context.EmpleadoJornada.Include(e => e.Empleado).Include(e => e.JornadaDiaria).Include(e => e.JornadaFinDeSemana);
            return View(await horasExtraDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

I have tried setting breakpoints but the program just passes through the RedirectToAction method. I see the URL changes when $.ajax is called but nothing else happens.I've also tried looking at the console to see the Ajax response after the call but nothing prints out.

EDIT:

I tried redirecting from the Ajax call like Md Farid Uddin Kiron sugested. Also, I added the "complete" section for testing purposes but it doesn't redirect to the index

AJAX call:

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: { data },
url: "/EmpleadoJornada/ActualizarJornada",

```
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = "/EmpleadoJornada/Index";
               
            },
            failure: function (response) {
            },
            error: function (response) {
            },
            complete:function(response){
                window.location.href = "/EmpleadoJornada/Index";
            }
            
        });
    });
});
```

In the controller method I just changed the "return RedirectToAction" to "return Ok();"

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I was hoping it would work  when I saw the GIF :(

Comment: Could you please share how did you implement? What did you return from your controller? In addition, how did you modifed your ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve the problem. The issue was that the input tag that I was using to save the info was type="submit" and that was causing the page to refresh. I changed it to type="button".

Sorry I didn't post that part of the code.

I appreciate the answers from you all!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct. Since redirects don't function with an AJAX post, my guess is that you're not performing a regular POST.

An AJAX POST redirect response is disregarded by the browser. When an AJAX call produces a redirect response, you will have to redirect from the script itself

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried setting breakpoints but the program just passes through
> the RedirectToAction method. I see the URL changes when $.ajax is
> called but nothing else happens.I've also tried looking at the console
> to see the Ajax response after the call but nothing prints out.

Well, as you are submitting ajax request which always expect a response and execute either of success or error and  your redirect won't executed because ajax request would always ended up with expecting response from the method you have submitted request to.

In other words, RedirectToAction will not act accordingly in case of ajax request you need to return json response and in client-side within your succeess function you have to redirect to index action where you would like to redirect.

Let's have a look how we can do that,

Ajax Request:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CallAjaxAndRedirect()" value="Submit Request" />

@section scripts {
    <script>
        function CallAjaxAndRedirect() {
            var data = "My data";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/EmpleadoJornada/ActualizarJornada",
                type: "POST",
                data: { data },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.href = "/EmpleadoJornada/Index";
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ActualizarJornada(string data)
        {
            //Your existing code...
            return Ok();
        }
```

Output:

[image]